# rsync only directories that exist?

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

On my local machine I have several plugins, and on the server I have a few.

Local Machine:

```
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin1
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin1/includes
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin2
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin3
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin4
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin5
```

Remote Machine:

```
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin1
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin1/includes
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin3
~/wp-content/plugins/plugin5
```

What rsync command can I use to update all the files in the remote directories, but only if they exist? For this I would like to have plugin1, plugin1/includes, plugin3, and plugin5 synced - with all files and directories inside - but not plugin2 or plugin4. Basically, update all of the plugins if they exist with a single rsync command.

Comment: Do you have a list of all plugin directories on the server?

Comment: I could run a command to get a list. Would I first need to do that for what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not completely possible with only one rsync command. If you only want to *update* the remote files, but do not want to add *new* files, you can use this command:

```
rsync -rP --existing source/ user@remote:target/
```

This will not create new files or directories at all, but update differing ones.

**Edit**: Maybe you could do something like this (assuming GNU find, if BSD/OS X: replace maxdepth with depth):

```
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE_TARGET_DIR=/some/path
REMOTE_DIRS=$(ssh user@remote "find $REMOTE_TARGET_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n' | sed 1d"
for DIR in $REMOTE_DIRS
do
  rsync -rP "$DIR" "user@remote:$REMOTE_TARGET_DIR/"
done
```

*Warning*: I have not tested this, you might want to add a "-n" to rsync (dry run) to see what happens.

Comment: Well, looks like this is the best option for now. If anyone has another solution, even using more than one command, please do share.